# Video CSS issue with mobile devices

Tags: css, viewport

I am wrapping a video with this code:

```
 .row-full {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -50vw;
  height: 780px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  left: 50%;
```

}

I can use 100vw for the width but I need to use the exact height for displaying the video correctly. THe problem is that on mobile devices the width resizes but the height stays the same. Is there a way to resize the height without using @media screen?
The URL where you can see the problem is the following:
[Link to example](https://pts2.theseolounge.co.uk/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```css
height: auto;
```

or Remove this from your code:

```css
height: 780px;
```

Comment: I tried both but there is another element that is creating the gap, namely: div.widget-area.fadeup-effect.fadeInUp

Comment: Remove inline height from front-page-1.

Comment: great stuff! It worked. It is not inline but added from god knows where. Anyway I did an override and it works.